# Install silently into microsoft/nanoserver

Tags: windows-10, container, silent-install, docker-for-windows

I have this excerpt from one of my Dockerfile[s]. Any attempt to install a software silently would fail. In another Dockerfile, I already had tried with oracle-xe without success. Here in this docker file, I also tried Git for Windows, OpenSSH, and gpg4win, none of them would work returning a very long return code.

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver
ADD assets/jdk-8u161-windows-x64.exe C:\\temp\\install
RUN powershell.exe -Command Start-Process C:\temp\install\jdk-8u161-windows-
x64.exe -ArgumentList '/s' -Wait
# Or
# C:\temp\install\jdk-8u161-windows-x64.exe /s
```

Can you help me solve this please?

Comment: Does the JDK install without the silent flag? What is the exit code?

Comment: Yes, on the host it installs without a problem, as do all other failing software.